# Socket programming between Java and TCL

Tags: java, sockets, tcl

I have to write a program for a scenario in which a java program will communication to the TCL program using socket programming.
I have successfully tried the socket programming for TCL and Java individually. But as I have to have a Java program as a client socket and TCL program as a server, I am not able to do it successfully.

## TCL program for server

```
set svcPort 9999

#Implement the service
# This example just writes the info back to the client...

proc doService {sock msg} {
  puts $sock "$msg"
}

# Handles the input from the client and  client shutdown
proc  svcHandler {sock} {
  set l [gets $sock]    ;# get the client packet
   puts "The packet from the client is $l"
  if {[eof $sock]} {    ;# client gone or finished
     close $sock        ;# release the servers client channel
  } else {
    doService $sock $l
  }
}

# Accept-Connection handler for Server. 
# called When client makes a connection to the server
# Its passed the channel we're to communicate with the client on, 
# The address of the client and the port we're using 
#
# Setup a handler for (incoming) communication on 
# the client channel - send connection Reply and log connection
proc accept {sock addr port} {

  # if {[badConnect $addr]} {
  #     close $sock
  #     return
  # }

  # Setup handler for future communication on client socket
  fileevent $sock readable [list svcHandler $sock]

  # Read client input in lines, disable blocking I/O
  fconfigure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0

  # Send Acceptance string to client
  puts $sock "$addr:$port, You are connected to the echo server."
  puts $sock "It is now [exec date]"

  # log the connection
  puts "Accepted connection from $addr at [exec date]"
}


# Create a server socket on port $svcPort. 
# Call proc accept when a client attempts a connection.
socket -server accept $svcPort
vwait events    ;# handle events till variable events is set
```

and

## Java client program

```
// File Name GreetingClient.java

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String serverName = args[0];
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                             + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress()+"\n");
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                    new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

1. I started the server, server shows nothing.
2. I started the client, server shows "Accepted connection from  at Mon May  6 02:50:21 PDT 2013" and the client shows
   "Connecting to  on port 9999
   Just connected to /(server ip address):9999"
3. As the out.writeUTF is executed in client, server shows "The packet from the client is `"Hello from : /<client ip address>:<client port no>".` But nothing is shown at client as it is supposed to show the reply from the server. The client process does not exit and waits for the execution of `System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());`.

Can someone please help here and tell why the client is not able to see the reply from the server when the connection is there, and client can send data to the server.

Thanks

Comment: Edit question by including the code that you used than using web-links.

Comment: One more modification in the java code I did was "out.writeUTF("Hello from : "+ client.getLocalSocketAddress()+"\n");"

Comment: If you do so by editing, it will be useful for us to help you.

Comment: You can manually test your server using telnet. For example telnet localhost 9999

Comment: The programs are taken from the working socket programming examples. I have tested them individually. So the server program worked fine when tested with the TCL client socket program.

Comment: @user They're speaking different protocols; `writeUTF` doesn't send what you seem to be expecting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Java client is using `DataOutputStream.writeUTF` and `DataInputStream.readUTF`; these use a simple framing protocol on top of the socket, which that Tcl server doesn't speak. This makes things go wrong.

The framing protocol is pretty simple. First, the *length* of the string (in bytes) is written as a two-byte big-endian ("network-endian") integer. Then the UTF-8 bytes of the string are sent. Pretty straight-forward, but you need to know in order to actually handle it right. You also want to put the socket in binary mode when working this way; you're not using a line-oriented protocol any more.

```tcl
# Two helper procedures that know how to do the framing encoding/decoding
proc writeJavaUTF {sock msg} {
  set data [encoding convertto utf-8 $msg]
  puts -nonewline $sock [binary format "S" [string length $data]]$data
}
proc readJavaUTF {sock} {
  binary scan [read $sock 2] "S" len
  set data [read $sock [expr {$len & 0xFFFF}]]
  return [encoding convertfrom utf-8 $data]
}

# This is your sample code, stripped of comments and adapted
set svcPort 9999
proc doService {sock msg} {
  writeJavaUTF $sock "$msg"; # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
proc svcHandler {sock} {
  set l [readJavaUTF $sock]; # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  puts "The packet from the client is $l"
  if {[eof $sock]} {
     close $sock
  } else {
    doService $sock $l
  }
}
proc accept {sock addr port} {
  fileevent $sock readable [list svcHandler $sock]
  # Next *three* lines are changed!
  fconfigure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0 -translation binary
  writeJavaUTF $sock "$addr:$port, You are connected to the echo server."
  writeJavaUTF $sock "It is now [exec date]"
  puts "Accepted connection from $addr at [exec date]"
}
socket -server accept $svcPort
vwait events
```

Comment: Note also that you probably ought to write code to handle short reads if you intend to send long messages. But for testing, it should work.

Comment: Also, if you vote this answer up or mark it as accepted, _please also give Johannes's answer a vote up_ as this is just a worked example application of the things he is pointing to.

Comment: I made the modifications you suggested but it is still not working. It waits at in.readUTF() in the java program. I forgot to mention, that my java client program is running on windows system where as the TCL server program is on the linux machine, I don't know how much it makes a difference. I have successfully executed the TCL scripts on the same linux system from the java programs on windows system. I had used JSch library for the same and I was able to get the results back. But I have to do it with socket programming to make it interactive.

Comment: Working now. Don't know why it was not working earlier why it is working now.

Answer (score 3):

You are using 2 different methods to communicate:

- Java's [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).[writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) adds the number of bytes send as the first byte. See [Java UTF Socket Communication](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11531) on the Tclers Wiki to see how you could read this.
- On Tcl side, you use newlines as terminator (`gets` only reads full lines.). If you want it this way use an [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/DataOutputStream.html) with the encoding `UTF-8`.

Comment: I am able to read on the server, the content that was sent by the client. But not vice versa.

I even tried 
    proc doService {sock msg} {
      puts $sock "FROM SERVER"
    }

but didnt work.