# Communication between master interpreter and slave interpreters in Tcl

Tags: sockets, tcl, interpreter

I am working on Tcl socket communication, where I am actually evaluating the commands sent by the java client to a tcl server. On each client's new request, I am creating new `interp` and deleting it while the connection closes.

The base code is taken with reference from other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16396660/974155) & [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408527/974155).

So far, no problem from Java code.

```
proc writeJavaUTF {stream string} {
     set data [encoding convertto utf-8 $string]
     if {[string length $data] > 0xffff} {
         error "string to long after encoding"
     }
     set len [binary format S [string length $data]]
     puts -nonewline $stream $len$data
     flush $stream
 }

 proc readJavaUTF {stream} {
     binary scan [read $stream 2] S len
     if {[info exists len]} {
     set data [read $stream [expr {$len & 0xffff}]]
     return [encoding convertfrom utf-8 $data]
     } else {
        return "NULL"
     }
 }


set svcPort 9999

proc svcHandler {sock} {
  global tclEngine
  puts "receiving socket request from $sock"
  set userTclCmd [readJavaUTF $sock]; # Reading the user commands over socket 
  puts "The command received from user : $userTclCmd"
  if {[eof $sock]} {
     puts "Socket $sock is closing it's connection. Going to delete it's interpreter"
     interp delete $tclEngine($sock)
     close $sock
  } else {
    catch {interp eval $tclEngine($sock) $userTclCmd} cmdResponse
    puts "My response : $cmdResponse"
    writeJavaUTF $sock $cmdResponse; # Writing the response over socket 
  }
}
proc accept {sock addr port} {
  # Once connection is made, then creating a new slave interpreter 
  # for the client
  global tclEngine
  set tclEngine($sock) [interp create]
  fileevent $sock readable [list svcHandler $sock]
  fconfigure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0 -translation binary
  puts "Accepted socket connection from $addr on port $port "
}

#Tcl Array Engine to hold reference of all the client Tcl interpreters
array set tclEngine {}
# Listening for client requests
socket -server accept $svcPort
puts "I am waiting ..."
vwait events
```

With the `readJavaUTF`, I have added one check from my side.

```
if {[info exists len]} {

}
```

**Question 1:**
When the connection closed from the client side, by means of `client.close()` at that time also `readJavaUTF` is being called. Why is that so ? Earlier, I have plainly used the version as per your (i.e. Mr.Donal's code) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408527/974155).

But, I got the following error

```
can't read "len": no such variable
    while executing
"expr {$len & 0xffff}"
    (procedure "readJavaUTF" line 4)
    invoked from within
"readJavaUTF $sock"
    (procedure "svcHandler" line 4)
    invoked from within
"svcHandler sock280"
```

To handle this, I just added that piece of code.

**Question 2 :** 
How to interact with master interpreter from the slave and vice versa. Say, I have to access a variable from the master's global space. Is that possible ? Before that, whatever the approach I am following right now is a good one ? Any other suggestions or improvements ?

Comment: Apart from not using braces round the `catch` as in `if {[catch {…} result]} {`? Nothing obvious to me.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. Corrected now. Wondering if I'm making mistake in client-server communication. By the way, I'm following your conventional approach only from  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16408527/974155. Will update the post with proper code soon. Give me 1 hour. I'm in travel.

Comment: @DonalFellows : I managed to solve the `catch` issue. It is working. I have updated my question. Still have some other queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First question: End-of-file handling in fileevent callbacks

Tcl calls read callbacks when exception cases happen. You should use the `eof` commands to check for that sort of thing after doing the `read`.

```
set data [read $stream 2]
if {[string length $data] == 0 && [eof $data]} {
    # Closing unregisters all fileevent handlers too
    close $stream
    return
}
binary scan $data S len
```

---

### Second question: Sharing variables between interpreters

Variables are not shared between interpreters at all. Although Tcl has global variables and uses them quite a lot, they're *only* global to that interpreter. All other interpreters have their own variables. (The exception is the `env`, which is effectively globally shared. Only use it for passing information to subprocesses or to get information from the OS; it's quite a lot slower than virtually every other approach.)

Commands can be aliased (with `interp alias`) in a slave interpreter so that they can be implemented by the master interpreter. This mechanism, which is somewhat analogous to how a system call works, lets the slave get access to an exactly controllable profile of functionality; anything not aliased in (and not internally implemented by the slave) is completely beyond reach. You can then easily use this to implement access to variables in the master in a safe fashion.

```
proc read_my_vars {permittedList varName {value ""}} {
    if {$varName ni $permittedList} {
        return -code error "no such variable \"$varName\""
    }
    upvar "#0" $varName var
    return $var
}
proc write_my_vars {permittedList varName value} {
    if {$varName ni $permittedList} {
        return -code error "no such variable \"$varName\""
    }
    upvar "#0" $varName var
    set var $value
}

interp alias $slave READ {} read_my_vars {a b c}
interp alias $slave WRITE {} write_my_vars {a b c}
set a 1
set b 2
set c 3

$slave eval {
    puts "a = [READ a]"
}
```

You can even use a trace in the slave to make this transparent:

```
$slave eval {
    trace add variable a read {apply {args {READ a}}}
    trace add variable a write {apply {args {global a;WRITE a $a}}}
}

$slave eval {
    puts "a = $a"
}
```

Comment: @ Donal Fellows :  Thanks for the clear explanation. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly access variables in the master interpreter. You would need to implement a command in the master and aliased in the slave to do that. Something like

```
% interp alias slave shadow {} variable_access
shadow
% proc variable_access {var args} { uplevel #0 [list set $var {*}$args] }
% set x 2
2
% slave eval {shadow x}
2
% slave eval {shadow x 5}
5
% slave eval {shadow x}
5
```

**You don't want to use the above as is since you will lose all protection. Check for specific variable names that are allowed and maybe only allow reads.**

You might be able to provide an illusion of direct variable access using traces in the slave.